# TELERIK: Calculate total of minutes between Two RadTimePicker

Tags: javascript, telerik

i have two radtimepicker and i want to create a javascript that will calculate the two of them to produce total minutes. my scenario is i want to calculate the total minutes of two hours seledted by the user:

example:

```
radtimepicker1: 09:00 AM
radtimepicker2: 10:15 AM

Total minutes: 75
```

this my code but no luck:

```
  function CalculateTotalMinutes(sender, eventArgs) {


        var timeFrom= $find("<%= timepickerFrom.ClientID %>");
        var varFrom= timeFrom.get_timeView();

        var timeTo= $find("<%= timepickerTo.ClientID %>");
        var varTo = timeTo.get_timeView();

        var txtNumDays = $find("<%= txtDuration.ClientID%>");

        if (varFrom <= varTo ) {


            var varSeconds = Math.ceil((varTo.getTime() - varFrom.getTime()) / 1000);
            var varMinutes = varSeconds / 60;
            txtNumDays.set_value(varMinutes);
        }
        else {

        }

    }
```

please help... thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function DateSelected(sender, args) {
            var timeFrom = $find("<%= RadTimePicker1.ClientID %>");
            var varFrom = timeFrom.get_selectedDate();

            var timeTo = $find("<%= RadTimePicker2.ClientID %>");
            var varTo = timeTo.get_selectedDate();

            if (varFrom != null && varTo != null) {
                alert(daysBetween(varFrom, varTo));
            }
        }

        function daysBetween(date1, date2) {
            //Get 1 day in milliseconds
            var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

            // Convert both dates to milliseconds
            var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
            var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

            // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
            var difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;
            //take out milliseconds
            difference_ms = difference_ms / 1000;
            var seconds = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
            difference_ms = difference_ms / 60;
            var minutes = Math.floor(difference_ms % 60);
            difference_ms = difference_ms / 60;
            var hours = Math.floor(difference_ms % 24);
            var days = Math.floor(difference_ms / 24);

            return days + ' days, ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes, and ' + seconds + ' seconds';
        }

    </script>
```

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadTimePicker ID="RadTimePicker1" runat="server">
        <ClientEvents OnDateSelected="DateSelected" />
</telerik:RadTimePicker>
<telerik:RadTimePicker ID="RadTimePicker2" runat="server">
        <ClientEvents OnDateSelected="DateSelected" />
</telerik:RadTimePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your codes to suit my needs.... thank you so much

```
function DateSelected(sender, args) {
        var timeFrom = $find("<%= RadTimePicker1.ClientID %>");
        var varFrom = timeFrom.get_selectedDate();

        var timeTo = $find("<%= RadTimePicker2.ClientID %>");
        var varTo = timeTo.get_selectedDate();

        if (varFrom != null && varTo != null) {
            alert(daysBetween(varFrom, varTo));
        }
    }

    function daysBetween(date1, date2) {
        //Get 1 day in milliseconds
        var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

        // Convert both dates to milliseconds
        var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
        var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

        var varSeconds = ((date2_ms - date1_ms) / 1000);

        var varMinutes = varSeconds / 60;

        return varMinutes + ' minutes';
    }
```